# Flush slow after update (Doctrine ORM + Symfony 2)

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, redis, flush

I was using Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine ORM 2.4. **After updating** Symfony to 2.6 and Doctrine ORM to 2.5 the flush operation is **really slow**. I found out the problem is in the function `computeChangeSets()` in `UnitOfWork`.
On the production system I'm using redis for doctrine caching and I also got the error `RedisException "Redis server went away"`. If I check in console the redis server is working.

My dev settings in config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:         %database_driver%
                driver_class:   %database_driver_class%
                host:           %database_host%
                port:           %database_port%
                dbname:         %database_name%
                user:           %database_user%
                password:       %database_password%
                options:        %database_options%
            admin:
                driver:         pdo_pgsql
                host:           %database_host%
                port:           %database_port%
                dbname:         %database_name%
                user:           %database_user%
                password:       %database_password%
                options:        %database_options%
     orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        default_entity_manager: default
            default:
                entity_listener_resolver: %entity_listener_resolver%
            admin:
                connection: admin
```

And production:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                metadata_cache_driver:  redis
                query_cache_driver:     redis
```

Answer (score -1):

It was problem in decryption. We use enycription for some data in database. So when decryption occured when EventListener was called it realy slow the process. To fix the problem we didn't get data throught entity (but as array) so the event listener wasn't called.

PS: Slow working has nothing to do with upgrade.

PS2: **Problem with Redis still remains.**